# Why does it not ask me for input?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Tutorial {
    public static void main (String args[]){
        System.out.println("Who goes there?");
        Scanner name = new Scanner(System.in); ## I am asking for input form user but it does not take imput
        if (name.equals("me") || name.equals("Me") ){
                System.out.println("Well, good for you smartass.");
        }else System.out.println("Well good meet");
        }
    }
```

Why does the program run the else and not ask for my input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You merely created a Scanner but did not tell it to read something from the standard input. You can do that by calling `scanner.next()` to read a token `scanner.nextLine()` to read a line, etc. As well you are comparing a `Scanner` to a `String` in the if-statement.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Tutorial {
    public static void main (String args[]){
         System.out.println("Who goes there?");
         Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
         String name = s.next(); // get the token
         if (name.equals("me") || name.equals("Me") ){
            System.out.println("Well, good for you smartass.");
         } else System.out.println("Well good meet");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks that fixed it. Other super simple question. how do I print "name". When I try print() I get a long string of text.

Comment: @DarkAriel7 to print it in the else statement for example you would do `System.out.println("Good to meet you "+name)`. You are getting a long string cause in your code `name` is the Scanner and println was printing the memory location of the object.

Answer (score 4):

You should read your input by using `scanner.nextLine()`:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String name = scanner.nextLine();
if (name.equals("me") || name.equals("Me"))
{
    System.out.println("Well, good for you smartass.");
} else {
    System.out.println("Well good meet");
}
scanner.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

You've only created an instance of the Scanner object. You need to invoke a method such as [`Scanner#nextLine()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29) to read input and then compare the read value to "me" or "Me".

Example:

```
Scanner name = new Scanner(System.in);
String input = name.nextLine();
if (...) // Compare input to something here.
```

You might want to use [`String#equalsIgnoreCase`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase%28java.lang.String%29) for case-insensitive matching too.